# chartjs: How to create single outer border for stacked barchart

Tags: chart.js

I have a stacked barchart for which I can pass a border color to each stack. Passing the same borderColor to each stack would also result in a border in the middle(yAxis=1.0) of the barchart.

I want to create a single outer border is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Like you want a specific color for the in-between part  or remove the border from one bar ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the borderwidth as an object and then set the with of the border to 0 where the stacks meet

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'red',
        borderWidth: {
          top: 0,
          left: 1,
          right: 1
        }
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'blue',
        borderWidth: {
          bottom: 0,
          top: 1,
          left: 1,
          right: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        stacked: true
      },
      x: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js"></script>

</body>
```