# ChartJS: single bar of bar chart. I want a border around entire bar, including the max Y-value

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, chart.js

I want to create a single bar using a bar chart. The setup is that the user can select different choices (representing the colors). In this example (codesandbox link below) I have a bar that has a max value of 90.000. The three chosen values are 20.000, 30.000 and 15.000, totaling 65.000.

Now, my goal is to have a border around this entire bar, not just the colors. In the image below this is represented with the red border. Currently I do this by putting a container element around my canvas element, but I would like to do this in the canvas itself, without using a container element. Someone has an idea on how to do this?

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-night-x6v0gv?file=/src/App.js)

[image]

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67593831/chartjs-how-to-create-single-outer-border-for-stacked-barchart). Hope that helps!

Comment: Not really, this just puts a border around the current highest value. 

eg in my example this would put the border around 65.000, not 90.000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define different [`dataset` properties](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.5.0/charts/bar.html#dataset-properties) such as `borderSkipped`, `borderRadius`, `borderWidth` to achieve what you're looking for.

Don't know why but I also had to define the `data` of the dataset at the bottom as a floating bar in order to see the rounded border.

```
data: [[0, 20000]]
```

Please take a look at the runnable code below and see how it could work.

```js
new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [''],
    datasets: [{
        label: "currentAmount",
        data: [[0, 20000]],
        backgroundColor: "#bbb",
        borderColor: "#f00",
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderSkipped: 'top',
        borderRadius: 30,
        barPercentage: 0.5
      },
      {
        label: "amount 1",
        data: [30000],
        backgroundColor: "orange",
        borderColor: "#f00",
        borderWidth: { left: 2, right: 2 },
        barPercentage: 0.5
      },
      {
        label: "amount 2",
        data: [15000],
        backgroundColor: "green",
        borderColor: "#f00",
        borderWidth: { left: 2, right: 2 },
        barPercentage: 0.5
      },
      {
        label: "remaining",
        data: [25000],
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        borderColor: "#f00",
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderSkipped: 'bottom',
        borderRadius: 30,
        barPercentage: 0.5
      },
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        displayColors: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        display: false,
        stacked: true,
        beginsAtZero: true
      },
      x: {
        display: false,
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```